# Set flag to database column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The task is creating sql script which set flag "Y" or "N" to existed dummy database line "Status" if integer value more or less '10'

database consists of three columns
person
money (5 or 100)
status (dummy - should be updated via stored procedure)

Solution is

```
update status set flag = "Y" where money = '5' and 
status set flag = "N" where money = '100'
```

Novice in SQL scripting

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE
  people
SET
  status = CASE WHEN money =   '5' THEN 'Y'
                WHEN money = '100' THEN 'N'
                                   ELSE status
         END
WHERE
  money IN ('5', '100')
```

Working backwards through that query...

- The `WHERE` clause ensures that only the rows you want to update are updated.
- The `CASE` statement then chooses which value to set `status` to based on the existing value in `money`.
- The `ELSE` block should never happen, but is there as a fail-safe *(in-case you forget to include the `WHERE` clause when you run it, the value of `status` gets set to the current value in `status` for any rows where `money` is neither `'5'` or `'100'`)*.

**EDIT :**

Notes:

- `people` should be the name of the ***table***
- `status` should be the name of the ***field***

**Final Edit (I give up now) :**

```
UPDATE
  people
SET
  status = CASE WHEN money > 10 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
;
```

This will update ***every*** row in `people`.

It will set `status` to `'Y'` if `money > 10`, for all other records it will set `status` to `'N'`.

Comment: mm ... there is a lot of values to money not only '5' or '100' I should pay attention on flag_conditions

Comment: @user2451093 - Your question states logic only for those two values.  Can you explain what logic you need to use for other values?  *(For example; If `flag` is already `'Y'` or `'N'` then do nothing, if `money` is less that 10 then set `flag` to `'Y'`, else set `flag` to `'N'`.)*

Comment: yes I can. I have got a lot of entities in that database which contains three columns person - money - status(dummy and should be updated by script Y or N)

Comment: @user2451093 - What do you mean by `entities`?  Do you mean tables, or rows?  Also, could you elaborate more on `there is a lot of values to money not only '5' or '100' I should pay attention on flag_conditions`?

Comment: This script's job is only set status "Y" or "N" to "status"-column of "people"-database

Comment: @user2451093 - A `database` doesn't have columns; a `table` has columns.  Do you mean that you have a ***table*** called `people` with ***columns*** called `person, money, status`?

Comment: @user2451093 - I've updated the answer.  This will process all ***rows*** in the ***table*** `people`.  First it uses the `WHERE` clause to pick which rows to process.  Second it uses the `CASE` statement to decide what value to put in to the `status` ***column***.

Comment: hmmm... Why we specified hardcode values ?  UPDATE
  people
SET
  status = CASE WHEN money > '10' THEN 'Y'
                WHEN money < '10' THEN 'N'
                                   ELSE status
         END
WHERE
  ???? money IN ('5', '100')

Comment: "money" contains different values 5 9 15 20 100 1000 150

Comment: @user2451093 - Because ***you*** specified them in your question.  That is why my first comment here *asked you* to specify the actual business logic required.  With regards to your suggested query; What should happen if `money = 10`?  And what should happen if there is already a `'Y'` or an `'N'` in the `status` field?

Comment: But could you update your script according to new logic with different values in money's row

Comment: but using the same flag's rule

Comment: @user2451093 - I can only update the answer when ***you*** have clearly specified the behaviour that you want, but you are not being clear and are not answering my questions.  **1.** `What should happen if [money = 10]?`  **2.** `What should happen if there is already a 'Y' or an 'N' in the status field?`

Comment: rule : if "money"-value more then "10" set Y ; if "money"-value lest then "10" set "N"

Comment: @user2451093 - ARGH!!!   But what about when `money = 10`???????????  I will no longer be replying to this thread or updating my answer.  I'm sorry, but I've asked you direct questions numerous times and you have singularly failed to answer them.  I give up.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible
>   result expressions.
>
> The CASE expression has two formats:
>
> • The simple CASE expression
>   compares an expression to a set of simple expressions to determine the
>   result.
>
> • The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions
>   to determine the result.

```
update [status]
set [flag] = 
    CASE 
        WHEN [money] = '5' THEN 'Y'
        WHEN [money] = '100' THEN 'N'
    END
WHERE   [money] in ('5','100')
```